# Error 500 when I open phpmyadmin of XAMPP

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin, xampp

I installed XAMPP ver 1.7.7 in linux mint, and when I open the link `/localhost/phpmyadmin` I get this error :

```
Erreur du serveur!

Le serveur a èté victime d'une erreur interne et n'a pas été capable de faire aboutir votre requête. Soit le server est surchargé soit il s'agit d'une erreur dans le script CGI.

Si vous pensez qu'il s'agit d'une erreur du serveur, veuillez contacter le gestionnaire du site.

Error 500

localhost
jeu. 12 sept. 2013 09:01:39 WEST
Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0c PHP/5.3.8 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.5 Perl/v5.10.1
```

Before installing xammp, I desinstall an old version of phpMyadmin. it was in the folder `/etc`.

Also, i have apache2 before. but it make no problem : I can see the home page of xampp.

Please where is the problem here ?

**P.S : I have no .htaccess in the directory /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin.**

thanks

Comment: Check webserver error logs to see cause of this error...

Comment: in the directory /opt/lampp/logs i have 4 files. all of them are empty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should not mix the Apache, PHP, MySQL and phpMyAdmin installations that come from Linux Mint, with a third-party product like XAMPP (unless you know exactly what to shut down in Mint to avoid problems in XAMPP).